# IntelliJ and WebStorm opening a file change

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, webstorm

When I use IntelliJ for Java or WebStorm for HTML/CSS I get this change (I think that that is the best way to say it): it basically removes my file tree from the left side of the screen and forces it up which makes me unable to find and open/edit files easily, sometimes I cannot even edit the files at all. (See the picture)

This has been really annoying since it forced me to use NetBeans instead of IntelliJ.

I hope someone is able to help me with this so I can use IntelliJ again.

[image: IntelliJ/WebStorm filechange]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the Project view, press Alt-1 (or Cmd-1 if you're using Mac OS X).

Comment: Thank you this is the anwser!